# Allow user interaction outside a non rectangular UIView content

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, cgpath, user-interaction

On a UIView that shows a circle image (needs to stay interactive), how would you prevent the area out side of the circle from receiving any user interactions, so the other ui under that view will still be active?

i tried masking the UIView with CGPath but that didn't help.[image]

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a touch event bubble down in the view hierarchy, as a UIView, you can check if a touch event is relevant to you, if it is not just return NO and that event will travel down to the next UIView in the hierarchy

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UIView * view in [self subviews]) {
        if ([view pointInside:[self convertPoint:point toView:view] withEvent:event]) {
            return YES;
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put any elements that receive UI events outside the circle.
If this is unavoidable, then just disable all of the elements outside of the circle for as long as you need.

Comment: I updated my title to - ALLOW user interaction, I need to get these 3 blue buttons under the image to get events even when under the overlapping alpha area between the circle image and the view frame.

Comment: If you need only part of a control to be active then just deactivate the entire control and put in an invisible button that only covers the area you want.

Comment: the invisible buttons will also become inactive if set interaction to false on the uiview. do you know any non-workaround way?

Comment: Nope. But don't set interaction to false on the entire `UIView`, just on the components you don't want to be interacted with. I'm pretty sure there isn't any non-workaround way (depending on your definition of a workaround).